# Constructing An if Statement with is_category(); in archive.php (WordPress)

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

I am trying to use an if statement with is_category() in order to build a bigger piece of code later. I can't get the code to recognize the if statement though. Basically below I've posted the coding with the if statement commented out. It works without the if statement but if I uncomment the if statement (and the closing curly bracket) then there is an error and the page doesn't display. I am only checking this on a category page so I assumed it should recognize that it is a category page and display the posts (I can understand it being a problem if I was on a 'tag' archive page, etc.). Why would this have a problem displaying?

### EDIT

I've included a bunch of code before the relevant code BTW so there is a context. The conditional `if (is_category())` works when applied to the title of the page (i.e. Archive for the NEWS category) but then just a little further down it doesn't work...

(btw, I do understand there is a WordPress stack exchange site but I rarely get answers to my questions on there. I have submitted this question there as well but thought someone could help me here as well, given that the answer is PHP related. Thanks!)

```
  <?php $post = $posts[0]; // Hack. Set $post so that the_date() works. ?>
  <?php /* If this is a category archive */ if (is_category()) { ?>
    <?php _e('<p>Archive for the &middot;</p>', 'life-is-simple'); ?><h1><?php single_cat_title(); ?></h1><?php _e('<p>&middot; Category...</p>', 'life-is-simple'); ?>
  <?php /* If this is a tag archive */ } elseif( is_tag() ) { ?>
    <?php _e('<p>Posts tagged &middot;</p>', 'life-is-simple'); ?><h1><?php single_tag_title(); ?></h1><p>&middot;...</p>
  <?php /* If this is a daily archive */ } elseif (is_day()) { ?>
    <?php _e('<p>Archive for </p>', 'life-is-simple'); ?><h1><?php the_time('F jS, Y'); ?></h1><p>...</p>
  <?php /* If this is a monthly archive */ } elseif (is_month()) { ?>
    <?php _e('<p>Archive for </p>', 'life-is-simple'); ?><h1><?php the_time('F, Y'); ?></h1><p>...</p>
  <?php /* If this is a yearly archive */ } elseif (is_year()) { ?>
    <?php _e('<p>Archive for </p>', 'life-is-simple'); ?><h1><?php the_time('Y'); ?></h1><p>...</p>
  <?php /* If this is an author archive */ } elseif (is_author()) { ?>
    <?php _e('<p>Archive for the author &middot;</p>', 'life-is-simple'); ?><h1><?php echo $curauth->display_name; ?></h1><p>&middot;...</p>
  <?php /* If this is a paged archive */ } elseif (isset($_GET['paged']) && !empty($_GET['paged'])) { ?>
    <?php _e('<p>Blog archives...</p>', 'life-is-simple'); ?>
  <?php } ?>

<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>

<ul style="list-style-type:none;">
```

```
<?php
/*if (is_category()) {*/
if ($paged == 0)
  $offset = 0;
else
  $offset = ($paged - 1) * 11;
global $post;
$category = get_the_category($post->ID);
$category = $category[0]->cat_ID;
$myposts = get_posts(array('numberposts' => 11, 'offset' => $offset, 'category__in' => array($category), 'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),'post_status'=>'publish'));
foreach($myposts as $post) :
setup_postdata($post);
/*}*/
?>
```

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: I'm getting a 500 Internal Error message.

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't the if is_category() check. You can verify that yourself by simply trying:

```
if(is_category()) {
  echo "category!";
}
```

When I tried running your code as-is I also "got an error." That type of super-error means the PHP is badly formatted, so badly that PHP couldn't even tell you where to look to fix the problem.

Here's how I rewrote the code so that it would run:

```
if ($paged == 0) {
  $offset = 0;
}
else {
  $offset = ($paged - 1) * 11;
}

global $post;
$category = get_the_category($post->ID);
$category = $category[0]->cat_ID;
$myposts = get_posts(array('numberposts' => 11, 'offset' => $offset, 'category__in' =>   array($category), 'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),'post_status'=>'publish'));
foreach($myposts as $post) {
  setup_postdata($post);
}
```

Comment: I tried to placed that code within the if(is_category()){} if statement and it did not work. This is within The Loop (not sure if that makes a difference). It just wasn't bringing the page up (the same error code I got with my code...500 internal error). I tried your code above without the if(is_category()){} and it didn't work then either. My code works, just not if I put it within the if(is_category()){} statement.

Answer (score 0):

like itecedor said, there's nothing problematic about your conditional ( apart from the not-so-usual but irrelevant, space after the keyword if)

i've changed the syntax for the foreach to a more conventional syntax and the 500 error is gone:

```
foreach($myposts as $post) setup_postdata($post);
```

Comment: That did not work for me whether inside the conditional or just as a replacement for the code already there...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you aren't terminating your foreach. If, While, and Foreach statements can be set up one of two ways:

**Less common method:**

```
<?php
if(true) :
    do_stuff();
endif;
while(true) :
    do_stuff();
endwhile;
foreach($arr as $var) :
    do_stuff();
endforeach;
?>
```

**Common method:**

```
<?php
if(true)
{
    do_stuff();
}
while(true)
{
    do_stuff();
}
foreach($arr as $var)
{
    do_stuff();
}
?>
```

You should set your code up like so:

```
<?php
if (is_category())
{
    $offset = $paged ? ($paged - 1) * 11 : 0;
    global $post;
    $category = get_the_category($post->ID);
    $category = $category[0]->cat_ID;
    $myposts = get_posts(array('numberposts' => 11, 'offset' => $offset, 'category__in' => array($category), 'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),'post_status'=>'publish'));
    foreach($myposts as $post)
    {
        setup_postdata($post);
        the_title(); //JUST SO YOU KNOW IT'S WORKING
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: The common method gave me the same 500 error. I literally copied and pasted it. Is there a way it could be conflicting with something else given the way the code is constructed?

Comment: BTW, I just added more code for context. As you can see, the conditional works in earlier code on the same page but for some reason doesn't work later on. Does it have anything to do with the (have_posts()) ?